# What oral medication can anti-inflame acne, without being antibiotic, Isotretinoin, or causing antibiotic resistance?

Tags: acne

> [More recently, sub-antimicrobial dose doxycycline has demonstrated superb efficacy as a first-line rosacea treatment.  Thus, despite increased bacterial antibiotic resistance, therapeutic efficacy persists due to anti-inflammatory effects of tetracyclines.1](https://www.hmpgloballearningnetwork.com/site/thederm/site/cathlab/event/tetracyclines-acne-and-rosacea)

**Aren't there  oral alternatives to antibiotics? Disregard Isotretinoin** because it has severe *permanent* side effects, and cannot be taken for some patients, e.g. [lipid panel abnormalities](https://www.physiciansweekly.com/the-value-of-lab-monitoring-during-isotretinoin-therapy). Even sub-antimicrobial doses of these antibiotics literally overkill, because

1. they kill probacteria, and
2. they are prescribed for anti-inflammation, not bacteriostaticity.

An anti-inflammatory, but not bacteriostatic, oral medication is better than antibiotics. Tetracyclines can cause antibiotic resistance, disorder gastrointestines, and  upset the gut flora.

Here I ask just about oral medications, NOT topicals here like Benzoyl Peroxide.

Graber, EM. Treating acne with the tetracycline class of antibiotics: A review. *Dermatological Reviews.* 2021; 2: 321– 330. https://doi.org/10.1002/der2.49

> In addition to the presence of *C. acnes*, inflammation also drives acne pathogenesis and the tetracyclines can aid in inhibiting inflammation as well. As a class, over 10 different anti-inflammatory effects have been reported with the tetracyclines. The tetracyclines decrease the production and secretion of proinflammatory cytokines such as interleukin-1β (IL-1β), IL-8, and tumor necrosis factor-α. By inhibiting these cytokines, chemotaxis and activation of neutrophils are suppressed.6 Tetracyclines also scavenge reactive oxygen species (ROS) and prevent oxidative damage to cellular macromolecules.5 Additionally, the tetracyclines downregulate proteinases such as matrix metalloproteinases that contribute to acne formation.10 It is because of these anti-inflammatory effects that some subantimicrobial dosages of tetracyclines, particularly doxycycline, have been shown to improve acne without exerting a bacteriostatic effect on *C. acnes*.10

> However, a subantimicrobial dose of 20 mg twice daily or 40 mg once daily may be given which has been thought to exert anti-inflammatory effects with no antibacterial effect—based on small clinical studies.54, 55 This subantimicrobial dose is not FDA-approved for the treatment of acne.

> Phototoxicity reactions are another relatively common side effect of doxycycline. Although the frequency of phototoxicity depends on geographic location and doxycycline dosage, phototoxicity rates of those taking antimicrobial dosages of doxycycline are reported to be as high as 42% with those taking 200 mg/day.60 With the lower anti-inflammatory dosages of doxycycline, the rates of phototoxicity are near zero.

https://www.hmpgloballearningnetwork.com/site/thederm/site/cathlab/event/tetracyclines-acne-and-rosacea

Comment: All your links and quotes are about tetracyclines, and you make no mention of the most effective acne medication of all, which isn't an antibiotic. Did you look for other medications at all? Type 'oral acne medications' into your favorite search engine and pick the first reputable site you find that isn't an ad. Mayo would be a good choice.

Comment: @CareyGregory I edited my post to rule out Isotretinoin, which you were hinting to.

Comment: Okay, then your response leaves me wondering what you're looking for. Some miracle drug that the world has somehow overlooked?

Comment: @CareyGregory I am merely hankering for an alternative to sub-anti-microbial doses of tetracyclines.

Comment: Why are you looking for oral medication? Topical, local treatment would have less side effects by default. I'm not sure if other anti-inflammatory treatments that restrict the immune system and not target the microbes (i.e. NSAIDs, Corticosteroids) would be a good idea risk/benefit wise.

Comment: The trouble is, if you've done a literature search and not found any new alternatives, it's extremely unlikely there is one. Drugs that are known to work will be on the lists published on all the usual sites, and new ones under development will be mentioned in the literature.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am not a dermatologist, and would not presume "it's extremely unlikely there is one". What about off label uses?

Comment: Being used off label doesn't mean under the table. Those would be mentioned on the general info sites. Any drug that's being used by a significant number of doctors to treat acne is going to be mentioned on WebMD, Mayo, etc. Any drug you can't find on those sites would probably be available only by enrolling in a clinical trial.